# How to find evidence of performance issues caused by too many threads on linux

Tags: rhel, performance, java

We have a RHEL 5 server, with 16 CPU cores, that runs a number of Java processes that get batch jobs submitted to them.  Each java process has about 80 threads that are used to process these jobs.  The server is currently overloaded during the batch processing, with load averages between 50 and 60.  I have observed the CPUs performing up to 60k context switches per second.

I suspect that reducing the number of java threads would decrease the number of context switches, and potentially speed up processing.

I am the sysadmin and only have access to the OS, and not the code that is being run.

How, from an OS perspective, can I gather evidence that this may be the case? Is it possible to quantify the delays that these waiting threads cause?

Comment: Submit the same batch job, multiple times, at 80, 40, 20 threads. Compare how long it takes that same batch job to be processed under the different thread counts. (You may also record context switches and whatnot but if 40 or 20 is faster, then that's good evidence 80 is too many for the given system independent of why.)

Comment: You can do some very low-level and complex snooping with Brendan Gregg's [perf tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools).

Comment: @meuh unfortunately, most of those tools won’t work on rhel 5.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at some of the perf tools, but as jsbillings states, they either don’t work or are not safe to run in a production environment.